# .NET MAUI Hot Reload Bug With Blazor

Tags: blazor, maui

I have created my first MAUI app with Blazor from the template supplied in VS2002 Preview.
I have not changed anything but when I run on the Windows machine and I change the index page and save (just any small change) I get a dialog [image]

Is this a preview bug or can I fix this with a workaround?
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.2.0 Preview 2.1

Comment: Note, VS 17.3 Preview 1 is out now - update it, and it should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar issue with .NET MAUI (without Blazor). The workaround I used is to exclude the other 3 folders (In your case: `Platforms` -> `Android`, `MacCatalyst`, `iOS`). And then in .csproj remove the targetframeworks of these 3, and leave up the one you're using. They say this issue is under investigation.

Comment: It's not worked for visual studio 2022  17.4.0 Preview 4.0  and dotnet core 6.